# How do I resolve protocol violation that occurs on only one table in Oracle 11?

Tags: java, oracle, protocols, talend, ojdbc

The protocol violation is only happening on one table out of many.

**Oracle DB Version:**  11.2.0.4.0

**Using:**  ojdbc6.jar

**Stack Trace:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.readRXH(T4CTTIfun.java:532)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:319)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOLOGOFF(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:61)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:491)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:3754)
at *********.run(***************.java:4900)
at routines.system.ThreadPoolWorker.runIt(TalendThreadPool.java:159)
at routines.system.ThreadPoolWorker.runWork(TalendThreadPool.java:150)
at routines.system.ThreadPoolWorker.access$0(TalendThreadPool.java:145)
at routines.system.ThreadPoolWorker$1.run(TalendThreadPool.java:122)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Just posting the error message isn't that helpful. Can you post both the code that is failing, and another sample that is working.

Comment: Sounds like there is bug in the JDBC driver that is being tripped by the length / character set / character data in that one table.  Is upgrading your Oracle JDBC driver an option?

Comment: try smaller cursor size, check if you receive this on a particular line, try to use the same / newer JDBC driver via different tool, for example SQL Workbench/J